# problems on getting the date range in listview

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetime, datetimepicker

This is the Code:

```
Private Sub btnSearchMaintDate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearchMaintDate.Click
    con.Open()
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblMaintenanceRpt WHERE dates BETWEEN '" & date1.Value & "' AND '" & date2.Value & "'", con)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        Dim lv As New ListViewItem
        With lv
            .Text = dr(1).ToString
            .SubItems.Add(dr(2).ToString)
            .SubItems.Add(dr(3).ToString)
            .SubItems.Add(dr(4).ToString)
        End With
        ListView1.Items.Add(lv)
    End While
    dr.Close()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

im having an error in the While dr.read it says SqlException was unhandled. The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value. But when I try to remove the single quotation in my query, it doesn't have an error but the result of getting the range of the date doesn't view in the listview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use parameter instead of appending dates in the string query :

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblMaintenanceRpt WHERE dates BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2", con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", date1.Value)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", date2.Value)
```

Using parameter also make your application less vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: this might be helpful, but i don't know how to use the code you'ved answer, ehehe xD

Comment: haha.. those 3 lines intended to replace this line of your code : `cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblMaintenanceRpt WHERE dates BETWEEN '" & date1.Value & "' AND '" & date2.Value & "'", con)`

Comment: ok, but there's something wrong with the semicolon, character is not valid

Comment: sorry, just remove them. it's C# syntax, not VB. I'm removing it from my answer now..

Comment: boom!, no problem man.your answer was very helpful.your the best :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore the time part of datetime values, you can use >= and < instead of BETWEEN (maybe time values are why you're not seeing any results).  It may be helpful to put `date1.Value` and `date2.Value` in a `MessageBox` to see what they hold.

Comment: like this?cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblMaintenanceRpt WHERE dates>= '" & date1.Value & "' AND dates<='" & date2.Value & "'", con)

Comment: Just `<` instead of `<=`.  @har07 has a good point about parameterizing, also.